# Moving Elements to back on focus

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good Evening,

I am having some issues with sliding elements using jquery I cannot seem to hide the inactive tabs on mouse over see example

http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/yeopiv4c

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/yeopiv4c

Comment: Tried moving z-index I think I will need to traverse and remove tabs via jquery I wish there was a simpler answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the z-index of the active tab on hover. I did so by giving each slide container a class called `slide` and using the following CSS

```
.slide { transition:z-index 1.5s; } // Prevent others from showing on close
.slide:hover { z-index:1; transition:z-index 0s; } // Hide others immediately
```

**NOTE:** This is a **bad** practice for UI design, users like to be able to see their options and be able to select them while hovering another. If this were my project I would do the opposite, lowering the z-index for active tabs so that all other tab icons are shown.

Side note: this can all be done in pure CSS using transitions and a lot less code (see below)

[**Demo**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/rqhkzrri), cleaned up, removed need for jQuery, shortened amount of code

**EDIT**

If we want it to do the opposite way, with all the tabs showing above the current tab, we have to use some javascript, sadly (because there is currently no previous sibling selector in CSS)

After removing the containers for the `tab`s/`slidewindow`s and placing the `tab` before it's respective `slidewindow` in the HTML, we can use the following script to do as we want

```
var slideWindows = document.getElementsByClassName('slidewindow'),
  tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');

for(var i = 0; i < slideWindows.length; i++) {
  tabs[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.right = "200px";
    this.nextElementSibling.style.right = "0px";
    this.nextElementSibling.style.zIndex = 1;
  }
  tabs[i].onmouseleave = function() {
    this.style.right = "0px";
    this.nextElementSibling.style.right = "-200px";
  }
  slideWindows[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.previousElementSibling.style.right = "200px";
    this.style.right = "0px";
    this.style.zIndex = 1;
  }
  slideWindows[i].onmouseleave = function() {
    this.previousElementSibling.style.right = "0px";
    this.style.right = "-200px";
    this.style.zIndex = 0;
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/4krmuhw9)

Comment: would it be possible to have the .tab class to open as to not hide them from the user also?

Comment: Yeah it moves the icons to the end so they can still be selected

Comment: Yes it is and it could *probably* be possible with the HTML you currently have with some perfectly timed z-index properties but by far the easiest way would be to restructure the HTML to not have a `slide` container and instead have all sibling elements, meaning something like `<.tab 1/><.slidewindow 1/><.tab 2/><.slidewindow 2/>...` in pseudo-code with the CSS `.tab { z-index:2; } .slidewindow { z-index:0 } .tab:hover + .slidewindow, .slidewindow:hover { z-index:1; }` if that makes any sense to you

Comment: Sorry Zach I am not following to be honest. Will it just be a case of altering the .tab to transition on hover?

Comment: Pretty much. I mean taking the tab and content elements out of their container, positioning both in their current displayed position individually (because you can no longer use the container to do so), then using the z-indexes as I have above. I have used the same approach in the past without fail. If I have spare time in the next couple days I'll work on doing so, but please try yourself f you can

Comment: I think I can see what you mean if I change the transition to .sliders encapsulating them all it selects all the tabs but I cannot select each from here it just slides the whole thing out

Comment: I cant see to get it there Zach can you have a look for me? if I select .sliders it selects it and appears to do half of the job but then I cannot select other tabs!

Comment: @dlhj It turns out we can't make a pure CSS version with the tabs always on top (while retaining click/highlight functionality on the content) because there is no previous sibling selector, so I added a pure js fix for it